# How to make popup stay in the center of the screen.

Tags: jquery, css, popup

What I need to do to make popup appear in the center of the screen in the following scenarios.

1- Scrolling the window
2- Resizing the window
3- Window is resized that it equals the size of mobile phone screen.

Demo 'http://jsfiddle.net/mdsa/rDT7Y/'

Comment: add ..popupBox{position:fixed} in css code..

Comment: it is working. What about resize window?

Answer (score 0):

use this class instead of yours

```
.popupBox{
    display: none;
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2000;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    border-top: 1px solid #898989; border-bottom: 1px solid #898989;
        border-left: 1px solid #898989; border-right: 1px solid #898989;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 35px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #4a4a4a;
}
```

Comment: As you told to replace above css code instead of mine. After replace this code my popup came to left side and it's not work resizeable window.

Comment: Give me answer plz. How to resize window?